# Pseudo edits considered appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

If an old question gets edited, it will be pushed in the active question queue. Sometimes that leads to an upvote if someone notices the question or maybe even an answer.

Is it appripriate to *pseudo-edit* my question now-and-then to keep it in the active question queue, even if the edits don't add anything to the question?

I am asking for the case when someone did not get a satisfying answer to his/her question and it won't get attention anymore.

Comment: From that FAQ entry: *\[edit\] to provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself*. Trivial edits to draw attention to your post are not appropriate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That is even mentioned in the FAQ? Good catch!

Comment: If it happens often, that's likely to be noticed and render a few downvotes to compensate.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not appropriate at all.  This is one of the reasons why posts are changed to be community wiki after a certain number of edits.

This behavior, if noticed by a moderator (possibly as a result of a flag from someone who noticed it being bumped) may result in disciplinary action of some sort.

Appropriate ways of drawing attention to a post include:

- making *meaningful* edits that truly add value.
- Adding a bounty to the question

Comment: Indeed. Or, as written in [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions): *"You can "bump" your thread by editing the question to **provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**."*

Comment: @Arjan He's referring to editing an answer, not a question, so that wouldn't apply.

Comment: Well, *"I am asking for the case when someone did not get a satisfying answer to his/her question and it won't get attention anymore."* :-) Anyway, I guess we agree.

Comment: @Arjan He edited that in afterwards, and it conflicts with his previous statement of, "Is it appripriate to pseudo-edit **my answer**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Oh - that was a typo. I meant **question**. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is definitely abuse of the edit system, especially if the question has lost relevance by having an accepted answer or by being closed.

If your edit adds significant content or fixes a problem with the post, by all means make an edit.

If you simply want to draw attention to an old post, there are other avenues, such as a chatroom.